# Weighted Sorting Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Given a permutation of $n$ element and for each pair of position $i$ and $j$, a non-negative integer $c_{ij}$ which is cost of swapping $i$-th element and $j$-th element of permutation.

Is there any polynomial or pseudo-polynomial algorithm to sort the permutation with minimum cost?

Comment: Is this a fictional or a part of research problem?

Comment: It is generalized form of part of a research problem.